# How can I retrieve existing data from an SQL Server database while updating many rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server, transactions, timeout, freeze

We have a program that parses a few files every half hour and inserts or updates the data in a MS SQL Server database. The problem is that it seems as if the program commits many operations in one go. In the past, this wasn't a problem but recently the parsed files have significantly increased in size and now every half an hour the database becomes unresponsive for 5 or so minutes and we can't perform a simple select statement while the program finishes committing whatever changes it makes.

We can't change the program, so how can I make the database retrieve the old rows while the program finishes committing its changes instead of just timing out as it currently does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change the isolation level of the database to use Read committed snapshot isolation.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/snapshot-isolation-in-sql-server

Have a read of this article to get a good understanding of the implications of switching RCSI to on. It may cause a performance hit and may give you unwanted results, so test!: https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/01/implementing-snapshot-or-read-committed-snapshot-isolation-in-sql-server-a-guide/

Comment: Thanks for the info. I turned the feature on and so far it seems to be working OK but I'll continue to monitor the performance.